# Java Generics in Builder

Tags: java, generics, builder

How can I use generics propery in my particular case? The code first, then the explanation:

AbstractConstraint.java

```
public abstract class AbstractConstraint {
    public abstract Constraint[] getConstraints();
}
```

AccountConstraint.java

```
public class AccountConstraint extends AbstractConstraint {
    private Constraint<Range<Integer>> accountIdConstraint;
    private Constraint<String> usernameConstraint;
    private Constraint<String> passwordConstraint;
    private Constraint<String> emailConstraint;

    private AccountConstraint(Builder builder) {
        this.accountIdConstraint = builder.accountIdConstraint;
        this.usernameConstraint = builder.usernameConstraint;
        this.passwordConstraint = builder.passwordConstraint;
        this.emailConstraint = builder.emailConstraint;
    }

    @Override
    public Constraint[] getConstraints() {
        return new Constraint[] {
            this.accountIdConstraint,
            this.usernameConstraint,
            this.passwordConstraint,
            this.emailConstraint
        };
    }

    public static class Builder extends ConstraintBuilder<AccountConstraint> {
        private Constraint<Range<Integer>> accountIdConstraint;
        private Constraint<String> usernameConstraint;
        private Constraint<String> passwordConstraint;
        private Constraint<String> emailConstraint;

        public Builder() {
            this.accountIdConstraint = null;
            this.usernameConstraint = null;
            this.passwordConstraint = null;
            this.emailConstraint = null;
            init();
        }

        public Builder accountId(final int val) {
            this.accountIdConstraint = new Constraint<>(operation, truthed, new Range<>(val), "accountId");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder accountId(final int min, final int max) {
            this.accountIdConstraint = new Constraint<>(operation, truthed, new Range<>(min, max), "accountId");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder accountId(final Range<Integer> accountId) {
            this.accountIdConstraint = new Constraint<>(operation, truthed, accountId, "accountId");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder username(final String username) {
            this.usernameConstraint = new Constraint<>(operation, truthed, username, "username");
            return this;
        }

        public Builder email(final String email) {
            this.emailConstraint = new Constraint<>(operation, truthed, email, "email");
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public AccountConstraint build() {
            return new AccountConstraint(this);
        }
    }
}
```

ConstraintBuilder.java

```
public abstract class ConstraintBuilder<T> {
    protected boolean truthed;
    protected Operation operation;

    protected void init() {
        truthed = true;
        operation = Operation.IS;
    }

    public ConstraintBuilder not() {
        truthed = false;
        return this;
    }

    public ConstraintBuilder like() {
        operation = Operation.LIKE;
        return this;
    }

    public abstract T build();
}
```

I want to be able to call `new AccountConstraint.Builder().not().username("test");` but this is not possible as I lose the 'reference to the builder' at `new AccountConstraint.Builder().not().`, ie. I cannot select `username("test")` anymore.

In what ways could I fix this? I do want that the `AccountBuilder.Builder` extends `ConstraintBuilder<AccountConstraint.Builder>` such that I do not have to duplicate the commonly shared methods then.

Regards.

---

**EDIT: I managed to get it working:**

See the answer below for the changes.

I hope I haven't broken any Java fundamentals with this solution, I hope it is more of a solution than a dirty hack.
I would be pleased if someone could review this edit.

Comment: I don't think you loose the reference. From `not()` you are returning `this`, which is still pointing to current instance which is `Builder`. May be I'm missing something. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, and the code does not work in Netbeans. For example `new AccountConstraint.Builder().` gives access to `not()` and `username(String)`. While `new AccountConstraint.Builder().not().` gives access to `not()` only. One particular thing is that in the latter `build()` would return type `Object`, while in the first it would return type `AccountConstraint`.

Comment: He doesn't lose the reference but he loses the type information (`not()` returns a `ConstraintBuilder`, not a `Builder`).

Comment: Ok. I missed that, as I said. You would need to typecast the reference back to `Builder`, and then you can proceed.

Comment: See my post on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862839/how-to-use-generics-properly-for-a-holder

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
Builder builder = (Builder) new AccountConstraint.Builder().not();
builder = builder.username("test");
```

Your issue is that:

```
new AccountConstraint.Builder().not()
```

returns a `ConstrainBuilder<T>`, which doesn't necessarily have access to `username(final String)`.  So, you cast it to a `Builder builder`, and then call `username(final String)` on `builder`.

EDIT:
You can turn this into one line:

```
   ((Builder) (new AccountConstraint.Builder().not())).username("test");
```

EDIT 2: 
You could override `not()` in Builder: make it call `super.not()` and cast the return to a `Builder`.  As in:

```
public Builder not() 
{
    return (Builder) super.not();
}
```

Comment: However a nice consequence of builders is usually that they can be written as oneliners. And that is one of the properties I would like to maintain in my code.

Comment: Okay it does work... But it is not really what I wanted, I can't imagine that it cannot be done without the casting, or am I wrong then?

Comment: I have managed to got it working, would you be so kind to check my answer I posted?

Comment: I think it's better to do one of the above casts than it is to modify your class in the proposed ways to account for one method call from a subclass.  I could be wrong, but it seems like `Builder` should deal with this problem, not `ConstraintBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need recursive generics.

Something like this should work:

```
public abstract class ConstraintBuilder<T, B extends ConstraintBuilder<T,B>> {
    private final Class<B> concreteBuilderType;
    public ConstraintBuilder(Class<B> concreteBuilderType) {
        if (!concreteBuilderType.isInstance(this)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong type");
        }
        this.concreteBuilderType = concreteBuilderType;
    }

    ...

    public B not() {
        truthed = false;
        return concreteBuilderType.cast(this);
    }

}
```

The concrete `Builder()` constructor would have to call `super(Builder.class)`.

Comment: You're right, doesn't seem that simple, I'll try a bit more.  For a simple solution using casting see my other answer.

Comment: Updated answer.  There is a (safe as long as the subclass passes its type correctly) dynamic cast in the abstract builder class.

Comment: Updated answer to check the type in the constructor so the dynamic cast is absolutely safe.

Answer (score 0):

If casting is acceptable, an alternative to Steve's answer would be to override methods like `not()` in `Builder` and narrow the type like this:

```
public Builder not() {
    return (Builder) super.not();
}
```

That way the caller doesn't have to cast each time.