# How to use generics properly for a Holder

Tags: java, generics, builder

I am trying to create a Holder class for different objects to be used in my application, I ended up with this code that works fine until some extent, the builder pattern works fine for the optional fields, but I guess this holder could be refactored to accept any arbitrarily number of parameter

```
package pojos;

public class Holder<T, R, S, U> {
private final T t;
private final R r;

private final S s;
private final U u;


private Holder(final Builder<T, R, S, U> builder) {
    this.t = builder.t;
    this.r = builder.r;
    this.s = builder.s;
    this.u = builder.u;
}


public T getField1() {
    return this.t;
}

public R getField2() {
    return this.r;
}

public S getField3() {
    return this.s;
}

public U getField4() {
    return this.u;
}


public static class Builder<T, R, S, U> {
    private T t;
    private R r;
    private S s;
    private U u;


    public Builder field1(final T t) {
        this.t = t;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder field2(final R r) {
        this.r = r;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder field3(final S s) {
        this.s = s;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder field4(final U u) {
        this.u = u;
        return this;
    }

    public Holder<T, R, S, U> build() {
        return new Holder<>(this);
    }

    public Builder<T, R, S, U> copy(final Holder<T, R, S, U> rowMappingsHolder) {
        this.t = rowMappingsHolder.getField1();
        this.r = rowMappingsHolder.getField2();
        this.s = rowMappingsHolder.getField3();
        this.u = rowMappingsHolder.getField4();
        return this;
    }


}
```

}

Example of usage:

```
protected Holder<Row, Map<Integer, String>, Void, Void> getRowMapHolder(Row row, Map<Integer,String> map) {
    return (Holder<Row, Map<Integer, String>, Void, Void>) new Holder.Builder<Row, Map<Integer, String>,Void, Void>().field1(row).field2(map).build();
}
```

Any ideas?

Regards

~Marco

Comment: "arbitrarily number of parameter" those parameters are of the same type?

Comment: No, as you can see the holder can contain objects of different types, see the "example of usage" uses only the first two, one holding a type "Row" and the second holding an object of type "Map", so the question here, is how to create a holder where we can pass multiple types and retrieve them in the order they were inserted in the Holder, so no more "field1", "field2"...

Comment: If you do not have an explicit structure/collection of values you are trying to maintain, it is much easier to just use a Map or Set as your holder, and throw an invalid argument exception if something about that holder is malformed (missing required parameter or something)

Comment: Use `Object...` in the method arguments, and `Object[]` in the fields... Also use getters/setters with index...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, and what about the Builder pattern?

Comment: I would recommend that you don't try to do this at all. The convenience of generic n-tuples is vastly outweighed by the sheer confusion as to what the different elements mean. (e.g. in a `Holder<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer>`, do you want the first? or the second? element). Create use-case specific types, where you can give the fields semantically-meaningful names. Check out [Google's AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value), which is a convenient way to avoid the boilerplate.

Comment: @AndyTurner. Thanks this is good stuff: https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md

Comment: I do not see what your `Builder` does, you pass arguments to it, but not in a constructor, but with setters, and then it returns the same instance every time, so not really building anything....

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto. The class has to be immutable, that is why the Builder pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andy's comment and Google Autovalue, a good solution arose:

So we can create different classes that have meaning, no more "field1", "field2"...

```
package pojos;

import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import java.util.Map;

@AutoValue
public abstract class RowMapHolder {

    public abstract Row row();

    public abstract Map<Integer,String> mapping();

    public static RowMapHolder create(Row row, Map<Integer, String> mapping) {
        return new AutoValue_RowMapHolder(row, mapping);
    }

}
```

or

```
package pojos;

import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@AutoValue
public abstract class KeyValuesMapHolder {

    public abstract List<KeyValue<String,String>> keyValues();
    public abstract Map<Integer,String> mapping();

    public static KeyValuesMapHolder create(List<KeyValue<String, String>> keyValues, Map<Integer, String> mapping) {
        return new AutoValue_KeyValuesMapHolder(keyValues, mapping);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How this should work for different number of parameters? You have finite number of accessors, so you cannot use, for example, `h.getField2147()`, if you don't declare it.

Another way to have a tuple for different number of objects is heterogeneous array. In Java, ofc, you may just use `Object[]` and you can wrap it with class, which have methods

```
public <T> T getField(int i) { 
    return (T) arr[i]; 
}
```

and then use like `h.<String>getField(2147)`

But creating different classes for tuples of different size (like your for 4 objects) is better.